# OpenGL fragment shader is moving objects

Tags: android, c++, opengl-es

I'm trying to write directional lighting into an OpenGL shader in a similar fashion to the one suggested in this Vuforia post:

https://developer.vuforia.com/resources/dev-guide/enabling-lighting-effects

However, the effect is rather dingy from this shader and is locked to the device, as though the light source is from the screen.  Instead, therefore, I've created a `uniform vec3f` which is manipulated by the model view projection matrix to allow me to lock a constant vector to the model frame (this bit seems to be working, by the way).  To counteract the dinginess, I increased the value of the ambient and diffuse light colour vectors, and I also added a slight yellow cast to the directional light and a slight blue one to the ambient light.

This caused some things to disappear; I guessed that possibly the shader was creating invalid colour values.  No problem.  I added a clamping system to the end that takes values from 0.9 to 1.1 and condenses them to the range 0.9 to 1.0 (a sort of primitive soft clip) and takes any values below 0.0 and clamps them to 0.0.

The upper bound clamping worked for some objects but not others.  The lower bound clamping has caused various objects to appear rotated at apparently random angles.

So what I assume is happening is something from my shader is overflowing into an adjacent memory location and screwing up the vertex rendering, but I don't know what.  Moreover, since I'm not writing to gl_FragColor till after the intermediate colour vector has been clamped, I can't tell why this would happen.  Can anyone make any suggestions?

Full shader code herewith:

```
static const char* cubeMeshVertexShader = " \
  \
attribute vec4 vertexPosition; \
attribute vec4 vertexNormal; \
attribute vec2 vertexTexCoord; \
 \
varying vec2 texCoord; \
varying vec4 normal; \
 \
uniform mat4 modelViewMatrix; \
uniform mat4 modelViewProjectionMatrix; \
void main() \
{ \
   gl_Position = modelViewProjectionMatrix * vertexPosition; \
   normal = modelViewMatrix * vec4(vertexNormal.xyz, 0.0); \
   normal = normalize(normal); \
   texCoord = vertexTexCoord; \
} \
";


static const char* cubeFragmentShader = " \
 \
precision mediump float; \
 \
varying vec2 texCoord; \
varying vec4 normal; \
 \
uniform sampler2D texSampler2D; \
uniform vec3 lightingVector; \
uniform vec3 diffuseMaterial; \
 \
void main() \
{ \
   vec3 n = normalize(normal.xyz); \
   vec3 lightDir = vec3(0.0, 0.0, -1.0); \
   vec3 ambient = vec3(0.5, 0.57, 0.6); \
   vec3 diffuseLight = vec3(0.9, 0.89, 0.87); \
   float diffuseFactor = max(0.0, dot(n, normalize(lightingVector))); \
   vec3 diffuse = diffuseFactor * diffuseMaterial * diffuseLight; \
   vec3 shadedColor = ambient + diffuse; \
 \
   vec4 intermediate = vec4(shadedColor, 1.0) * texture2D(texSampler2D, texCoord); \
   if(intermediate.x>0.9) { \
      if(intermediate.x<1.1) { \
         intermediate.x = intermediate.x / 2.0 + 0.45; \
      } else { \
         intermediate.x = 1.0; \
      } \
   } else if(intermediate.x<0.0) { \
      intermediate.x = 0.0; \
   } \
   if(intermediate.y>0.9) { \
      if(intermediate.y<1.1) { \
         intermediate.y = intermediate.y / 2.0 + 0.45; \
      } else { \
         intermediate.y = 1.0; \
      } \
   } else if(intermediate.y<0.0) { \
      intermediate.y = 0.0; \
   } \
   if(intermediate.z>0.9) { \
      if(intermediate.z<1.1) { \
         intermediate.z = intermediate.z / 2.0 + 0.45; \
      } else { \
         intermediate.z = 1.0; \
      } \
   } else if(intermediate.y<0.0) { \
      intermediate.y = 0.0; \
   } \
   gl_FragColor = intermediate; \
} \
";
```

EDIT: the OpenGL standard states that gl_FragColor is automatically clamped to [0,1], so my clamping system is unnecessary (though I will probably keep the soft clip).  However, this suggests that it's actually a side-effect of the shader's operation that's causing the problem, not an effect.

Comment: The overflowing you've described (your assumption) does not happen on GPUs and shaders. You can never overwrite memory that you are not supposed to overwrite from a normal shader. In theory, it could be a driver or hardware bug, but I *highly* doubt that.

Comment: That "clamping" part in your shader code is going to be very slow. Please consider a mathematical function or a look-up table. Also, for the sake of debugging, handle the case where your values are over 1.1. And you have at least one bug in there; the last conditional (`else if (y<0.0)`) should check and set `intermediate.z`, I believe.

Comment: And the line where you modulate your `shadedColor` with the texel value is a little suspect. I'm not sure whether this can happen normally or not, but if your texture lookup returns an alpha of 0 sometimes, and you have alpha blending or rejection enabled, you'll end up with a clipped fragment (i.e. probably what you are seeing now.) Could you change that line to `vec4 intermediate = vec4(shadedColor * texture2D(texSampler2D, texCoord).rgb, 1);` and check?

Comment: I think this was an NDK build bug.  Comments nevertheless very helpful, so thank you!

Comment: By the way, what mathematical function would be faster than a multiply followed by an add and have the effect of crushing the range in a similar fashion?

Comment: The problem is not that; it's all the non-coherent `if` statements. For example, you could have replaced the whole `if-else-if-else...` structure with this (assuming `vec3 x = intermediate.rgb;` and `vec3 edge = vec3(0.9, 0.9, 0.9);`, and sorry for the bad formatting): `vec3 over_edge = step(edge, x); 
vec3 delta = over_edge * (x - edge) * 0.5;  
gl_FragColor = vec4(clamp(x - delta, 0, 1), 1);`. I think this will do the equivalent of all your conditions and will be much faster.

Comment: Ah, so I could use vector arithmetic?  Would that handle a situation where eg red was 1.2 but yellow and blue were 0.8 such that only red would be clamped?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was actually cause by me stupidly failing to zero initialize some parameters in another edit; it was trying to rotate some objects by `NaN`.  I'm leaving the question here because the comments have some good advice about shader programming.

Comment: You should accept your own answer, so this doesn't remain unanswered.

Answer (score 1):

Light dir in your shader is constant, but lightdir should be the one from the object pointing to the light source, so it should be computed per vertex in your vertex shader

```
vec3 LightDir = normalize(gl_LightSource[0].position.xyz - vec3(gl_ModelViewMatrix * gl_Vertex);
```

Moreover one of your coef in Intermediate computation (clamping have an appropriate function: clamp) coulb be equal to 0.

this could be:

- your texture is not bound which will multiply by (0,0,0,0) your shadedColor.
- your diffuse material is not set
- your light vect is perpendicular to normal ( dot product = 0)

Comment: Actually I think it turned out to be an NDK build issue.  Thanks though!

Comment: this is still an issue that your light vector is constant in your fragment shader if objects are rotating in your scene

Comment: I want the vector locked to the object, so it's actually fine—I'm setting the vector value externally using a C++ function, which is what I want to do.  I don't need the lighting to vary per-vertex (the dot product is being used to compute the amount of directional lighting each fragment receives).

Comment: No problem, helpful anyway :)